# Two column layout in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display multiple elements in two columns in a react native application. This is what I have so far:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { viewStyle, childStyle } = style;

    return (
      <View style={viewStyle}>
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const space = 5;
const style = {
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: space,
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
  childStyle: {
    width: '50%',
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: space
  }
}
```

And here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRMmn.jpg

> My problem is: **How can I get some space in the middle (between the left and the right elements)?** And is it possible, that this also works when the user rotates the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a container with flexDirection: 'row', such that your columns are inside of this. Then have an empty View inserted between your columns:

```
    const {width, height} = require('Dimensions').get('window');

<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', width: width}}>
    <View style={[viewStyle, {flex: 5, flexDirection: 'column'}]>
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        ...
    </View>

    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    </View>

    <View style={[viewStyle, {flex: 5, flexDirection: 'column'}]>
        <View style={childStyle} />
        <View style={childStyle} />
        ...
    </View>
</View>
```

Difficult to maintain a fixed pixel dimension like this, but it will size on screen rotation. Alternatively you could just use padding in your column Views to have space between them. You could also disable screen orientation changes if you wanted to go that far. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the the space is fixed at 5px one solution would be to grab the width of the device from the `Dimensions` module. Each one the items in the row can be half of this width -2.5px. Change childStyle.width to reflect this number. Lastly render `<View style={{width: 5}} />` after every other item in the row and you should be all set. (This solution should work fine regardless of how the device is oriented)

Answer (score -3):

Add in your viewStyle: 
`justifyContent: 'space-between'`

Comment: This only works when I set for example `width: '49%'` on my `childStyle`. But what if I need to make sure, that the space between is exactly 5px?